# Using Message Broker for database replications (currently RabbitMQ )

Tags: rabbitmq, replication, messaging, messagebroker, apache-kafka

When my system's data changes I publish every single change to at least 4 different consumers (around 3000 messages a second) so I want to use a message broker.
Most of the consumers are responsible to update their database tables with the change.

(The DBs are different - couch, mysql, etc therefor solutions such as using their own replication mechanism or using db triggers is not possible)
questions

1. Does anyone have an experience with data replication between DBs using a message broker?
   is it a good practice?
2. What do I do in case of failures?
   Let's say, using RabbitMQ, the client removed 10,000 messages from the queue, acked, and threw an exception each time before handling them. Now they are lost. Is there a way to go back in the queue?

   (re-queueing them will mess their order ).
3. Is using rabbitMQ a good practice? Isn't the ability to go back in the queue as in Kafka important to fail scenarios?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into Event Sourcing? Maybe it'll suit your needs. It's not exactly a replication, but it could be better, especially if you have some notion of "commands" or "events" as a basis to change your data. Also It allows you to restore a database or a part of it. And no, RMQ won't allow to go back and it won't allow to restore acked messages (you could use a fanout exchange with extra queue though).

Comment: I know this is an old q, but I'm evaluating rabbitmq for exactly this scenario. Did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with DB replication using message brokers, but maybe this can help put you in the right track:

> ### 2. What do I do in case of failures?
>
> Let's say, using RabbitMQ, the client removed 10,000 messages from the
> queue, acked, and threw an exception each time before handling them.
> Now they are lost. Is there a way to go back in the queue?

You can use [dead lettering](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) to avoid losing messages. I'd suggest **to not ack** until you are sure the consumers have processed them successfully, **unless it is a long-running task**. In case of failure, `basic.reject` instead of `basic.ack` to send them to a dead-letter queue. You have a medium throughput, so gotta be careful with that.

However, the order is not guaranteed. You'll need to implement a manual mechanism to recover them in the order they were published, maybe by using message headers with some sort of timestamp or id mechanism, to re-process them in the correct order.